# git checkout branch after git add, seems not update index and working area

Tags: git

Here is my situation：

1. create a file `2.md` in branch `dev`, and `git add` this file, then I can see this file is added into index through `git ls-files`
2. switch to branch `master` by `git checkout master`, but `ls` and `git ls-files` still shows this file exists in working tree and index. **Why `git checkout` doesn't update working tree and index according to master's last commit?** 
   Here is the description of `git checkout` in git manual:

> To prepare for working on `<branch>`, switch to it by updating the index and the files in the working tree, and by pointing HEAD at the branch. Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept, so that they can be committed to the `<branch>`.

3. `git commit` this file in branch `master`, then `git checkout dev`, I find this file disappears from both working tree and index of branch `dev`, **which also confuse me**

Below is my operation and output:

```
(base) [root@zjmhost hello-github]# git checkout dev
Switched to branch 'dev'
(base) [root@zjmhost hello-github]# touch 2.md
(base) [root@zjmhost hello-github]# ls
2.md  copy.md  README.md  test.md
(base) [root@zjmhost hello-github]# git ls-files
.ipynb_checkpoints/README-checkpoint.md
README.md
copy.md
test.md
(base) [root@zjmhost hello-github]# git add 2.md 
(base) [root@zjmhost hello-github]# git ls-files
.ipynb_checkpoints/README-checkpoint.md
2.md
README.md
copy.md
test.md
(base) [root@zjmhost hello-github]# git checkout master
A       2.md
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 12 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
(base) [root@zjmhost hello-github]# ls
1.md  2.md  copy.md  README.md  test.md
(base) [root@zjmhost hello-github]# git ls-files
.ipynb_checkpoints/README-checkpoint.md
1.md
2.md
README.md
copy.md
test.md
(base) [root@zjmhost hello-github]# git commit -m "commit 2.md in master branch"
[master 005f0c2] 2.md do the same with 1.md
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 2.md
(base) [root@zjmhost hello-github]# git ls-files
.ipynb_checkpoints/README-checkpoint.md
1.md
2.md
README.md
copy.md
test.md
(base) [root@zjmhost hello-github]# git checkout dev
Switched to branch 'dev'
(base) [root@zjmhost hello-github]# ls
copy.md  README.md  test.md
(base) [root@zjmhost hello-github]# git ls-files
.ipynb_checkpoints/README-checkpoint.md
README.md
copy.md
test.md
```

Comment: When you checkout while there are pending changes in index, if the files _do not_ change between HEAD and where you are going, git assumes there's no issue checking out and allows you to do it bringing over your changes. It happens quite frequetly: **oops! Working in the wrong branch.**

Comment: After you commit, well, the file is in master. You go back to dev and sure enough, it's not there. I think you are assuming that just because you were on dev when you added the file to index, it should keep some relation to it? Well, that's not the case. The index will be used to create the new revision where you do (in your example, master) and nothing about dev is kept (after checking out master, git _forgets_ that you were in dev.... well, kind of... you still get to have the luxury of reflog).

Comment: Doesn't look like you `git commit -m` after you added it.

Comment: Related: [switching branches with uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452)

Answer (score 4):

You are, I think, right to be concerned and surprised.

Checking out a branch *is* sort of scary, because it *does* involve writing to the index and working tree. The safest way to switch branches is to commit first, either using `add-and-commit` or using `stash` (which is a form of commit). If `git status` says there is nothing to know, you are safe to switch branches.

In general, however, `git checkout/switch` will not overwrite or remove uncommitted work. I say "in general" because one does hear horror stories where work is unaccountably lost. All the same, if `git checkout/switch` would cause damage, Git is supposed to stop and warn you instead of doing the checkout.

I'll describe four cases; I think these are representative of the most common scenarios. I will use `switch` throughout, rather than `checkout` (a command I haven't given in a long time), and I will use the name `main` rather than `master` to signify the primary branch (as it is now the default).

#### Edit an existing file and create a branch

I start with the most commonly encountered base case, mentioned by `eftshift0`: you start editing and then realize you should have been on a branch. Let's posit this:

```
* (HEAD -> main) created c
* created b
* created a
```

Now I edit an existing file, and I even add the new state of that file to the index, ready to commit. But then I think I should have been on a branch instead:

```
% pico c
% git add c
% git switch -c br
% git commit -m'edited c'
```

No problem! The edited version of `c` is now in the `br` commit, and the previous version of `c` is in the `main` commit, as you can readily discover just by peeking:

```
% git show main:c
% git show br:c
```

Why was the branch switch okay? That's an easy one: it's because *nothing happened*. At the time of the switch, `br` and `main` pointed to *the very same commit.* Therefore there was nothing to do. The index and the working tree were left alone.

#### New file and switch to an existing branch

Now let's posit this initial situation:

```
* (br) created z
| * (HEAD -> main) created c
| * created b
|/  
* created a
```

We're on `main` and we create a *new* file (`d`) and add it, and then, without committing, we switch to `br`, which already exists and points to a different commit:

```
% pico d
% git add d
% git switch br
% git commit -m'created d'
```

Again, no problem! Although `br` is a different commit altogether, nothing about `d` is known in `main` or `br`; it isn't a file in either of them. So Git permits this, and the new file `d` just "comes across" with the switch, and we can commit the index that we configured while we were on `main`.

#### Edit an existing file and switch to an existing branch

Return now to this initial situation:

```
* (br) created z
| * (HEAD -> main) created c
| * created b
|/  
* created a
```

We're on `main` and this time we edit and add the file `c`, which already exists in `main`, just like in the first scenario, and then we try to switch to the branch `br` which, *unlike* the first scenario, already exists and points to a different commit:

```
% pico c
% git add c
% git switch br
error: Your local changes to the following files 
would be overwritten by checkout:
    c
Please commit your changes or stash them before 
you switch branches.
Aborting
```

This time, Git *refuses to make the switch.* There is a file `c` in `main`, and the state of that file `c` in the working tree is different from that, and the state of file `c` in `br` is different yet again — namely, it doesn't exist. Therefore checking out `br` would mean changing (in this case, removing) the file `c` in the working tree. That's an overwrite, and Git balks.

#### Edit an existing file and switch to an existing branch which contains that same file

This one might be regardded as an edge-case subset of the previous example (also pointed out to me by `eftshift0`). We start with a very slightly different situation:

```
* (br) created c
| * (HEAD -> main) created c
| * created b
|/  
* created a
```

Here, we are on `main`, which contains file `c` — and meanwhile the branch `br` *also* contains file `c`, which (we stipulate) is *in exactly the same state*. I now edit `c` and then try to switch to `br`, *and I succeed:*

```
% pico c
% git switch br
Switched to branch 'br'
```

This time, Git allows the switch. This is because the state of `c` in `br` will not tromp on the state of `c` in `main`, as they are *the same state.* The modifications I have made to `c` in the working tree are not lost; they "come along for the ride", as it were, as I can confirm by looking at `c` (with `cat c`) and by checking `git status`:

```
% git status
On branch br
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   c
```

It is also possible, in this situation, to `git add` the file `c` (to the index, in its modified state) and still switch branches. The state of the file `c` in the working tree and the index, in short, is irrelevant; what matters is its state in the two branches, the one we are on and the one we are switching to — if those are identical, the switch is permitted.

Comment: This is all good.... but I think you need to add/explain the case when you modify a file that is the same between `HEAD` and where you are going (which git would allow to take place).

Comment: Yeah, that's the case you cover at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44331118/341994. I'll see how to add it here...

Comment: @eftshift0 Here you go, I think that covers it.

Comment: Looks great,.... I'd like to point out that if it's in index or not makes no difference in this scenario.... the checkout would take place and the file would not be touched from what it is in index and working tree.

Comment: @eftshift0 So you're saying I could have omitted `git add` and still made the switch.

Comment: Yep.... give it a try... as long as the file is the same between `HEAD` and where you are going, `git` is fine with it.

Comment: @eftshift0 yep, confirmed. I think this just about wraps it up.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the [confusing old `git checkout` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309), try instead using [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch):

```
git switch master
git restore -- .
```

From the man page:

> The working tree and the index are updated to match the branch. All new commits will be added to the tip of this branch.

Comment: Even with `git switch` will uncommitted contents still exist in the index and local working copy?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, a git restore would be needed to... well restore the working tree.

Answer (score 0):

> Why git checkout doesn't update working tree and index according to master's last commit?

I think the key part you are missing is:

> Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept

In other words, the uncommitted changes in the index or local files will still remain. Since you didn't commit the changes to `dev`, they just carry along as you checkout `master`.

> git commit this file in branch master, then git checkout dev, I find this file disappears from both working tree and index of branch dev, which also confuse me

You just committed the new file to `master` but never committed it to `dev`. So you shouldn't expect the file to exist when you checkout `dev`.