# Abandon current Git branch, without committing

Tags: git

Every once in a while, I use a test branch for experimentation... I can commit the experimental branch, checkout the previous branch, and then delete the experimental branch...

I am looking for a way to simply abandon the experimental branch when I am done with it... I figured just swapping branches would abandon the changes, but this actually keeps all of the new files, even after changing branches. The only way I have right now to make this work is the three-step process I listed above...

I have read the Git documentation a few times now, so I am thinking there may be a way to use the 'Rebase' command to make this work? I will appreciate getting pointed in the right direction on this one.

Comment: Why are you committing the changes just to delete the branch? If you don't want them, _reset_ them.

Comment: Because I don't know any better... That is why I am asking the question... It seems like git reset --hard will do exactly what I am looking for tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are abandoning without committing, then you never needed an experimental branch to start with. You've done things in the wrong order. Do it like this:

1. Stay on the real branch.
2. Do some initial experimentation.
3. Decide whether to abandon or keep moving forward in the experiment.

   1. If abandon, `git reset --hard` etc. as described in other answer.
   2. If keep moving, `git switch -c experiment; git add .; git commit` and now keep working on the experimental branch.

Comment: If you don't understand why and when files get "left behind" when you switch branches, see my https://stackoverflow.com/a/67453215/341994

Comment: My initial branch is a base branch... The other branches stem from that one... The goal is not to keep merging everything into the main branch. The main branch operates as a template branch... The plan is to have a base branch for Unity's render pipeline, and I can branch off of this for separate games... This allows for experimentation, off of a base template of code.

Comment: Of course, but that is not in the least germane to what I just said

Comment: Oh... Now I see what you mean... I thought you meant commit to the base branch for some reason... Which would muddle it up... Now I see what you mean. I can use reset to get rid of the new stuff... Ok, sorry for that. I will have to give that a shot! I don't even remember the reset command from reading through the documents -.-

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel all your change with `git reset --hard`
Untracked files will remain you can delete them with `git clean`

So from an existing branch you do your experimentation then

```
git reset --hard
```

to reset all your change
Then

```
git clean -fd
```

to remove untracked files and directory

You can do a dry run to tell you what files will be removed

```
git clean -n
```

This will only list the files, to list down the folders use

```
git clean -nd
```

Comment: This answer also works. I can't choose two answers tho ;P