# How does the filesystem looks like when using git?

Tags: git

Locally I have a master branch with a committed file. I create a feature branch off the master, and after this I am on the feature branch,  and I edit the file.

When I checkout master, I also see the edit in the file.

When I checkout the feature branch, and commit the edit, and checkout master then I do not see the edit anymore. This is how it has to be.

But I don't understand how git does do this. So apparently the edit is on the filesystem before the commit, in whatever branch you are. But after the commit, not.

Comment: take a look at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: Git tries really hard to not blow away any work you haven't committed yet. An uncommitted edit isn't on any branch and is just sitting there waiting for you to do something with it. Git will let you change branches without touching that file as long as the commit you are moving away from, and the commit you are moving to, both have the same committed version of that edited file. If that isn't true Git will error and won't let you change branches, because it would need to modify the file, and if it did that, you might lose your unsaved copy of it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67453215/341994

Answer (score 0):

The root directory of your repository where you see all the files is called the `worktree` (see also the [`GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) and it contains the currently checked out files.

All other files holding the history of the repository, other branches, tags etc. are (by default) in the `.git/` subdirectory of the worktree (see the [`GIT_DIR` environment variable](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables)).
For details on how all the internal data ist stored in this directory see the git internals docs as suggested by [`eftshift0` in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78029761/how-does-the-filesystem-looks-like-when-using-git#comment137561529_78029761).

---

The reason you are seeing the "weird" behavior with uncommitted changes is as [`TTT` put it in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78029761/how-does-the-filesystem-looks-like-when-using-git#comment137563301_78029761): *Git tries really hard to not blow away any work you haven't committed yet.*

Using [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) or [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) you can switch between branches and `git` will bring all the files in your worktree into the state they are in the selected branch. I.e. checking out another branch you should see the contents of the files in your worktree as they are committed to the selected branch.

**But**: with uncommitted changes `git` behaves a bit differently in order not to lose your unsaved changes:

- *if possible*, `git` will checkout the new branch and re-apply the uncommitted changes to it
- if this is not possible without conflicts, `git` will refuse to checkout the other branch

So, the reason you still see the uncommitted changes after switching branches is that `git` carries them along. You can verify this with `git status` which will show you that there are uncommitted changes.
But as soon as you commit them they are saved and switching branches now will checkout all files to the state in the new branch - i.e., without those changes.